# Get order/shipment details by tracking number magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is there anyone has experience to get order or shipment details by tracking number?

I saw few rest apis available in magento 2.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

```
POST   /V1/returns/:id/tracking-numbers
GET    /V1/returns/:id/tracking-numbers
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inject `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\CollectionFactory` into your class constructor and filter by `track_number`:

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\CollectionFactory as TrackCollectionFactory;

class Example
{

    /** @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\Collection */
    protected $trackingCollection;

    public function __construct(TrackCollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->trackingCollection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getShipmentDetailsFromTrackingNumber($number)
    {
        try {
            $this->trackingCollection
                ->addFieldToFilter(ShipmentTrackInterface::TRACK_NUMBER, $number);
            /** @var Shipment\Track $tracking */
            $tracking = $this->trackingCollection->getFirstItem();
            /** @var Shipment $shipment */
            $shipment = $tracking->getShipment();

            return $shipment->getData();
        }
        catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {}

        return null;
    }
}
```